# Anyone know of a way to find all certs that weren't auto-enrolled?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I'm in the process of moving an Active Directory Certificate Services role over to a new 2012 server.  The new server will be issuing new certs and I need to find all certs that weren't handed out by auto-enrollment so I can manually issue new ones.

Anyone know of a good way to do this with Powershell preferably?  I'm using the PSPKI module.

Comment: if you are moving your CA you should also move/migrate the private key and database of that CA so those certificates that has been issued by that CA should still be valid, apart from had been autoenrolled or not. So why do you need to ask for those not autoenrolled certificates?

Comment: The old CA's been around for a very long time and was neglected.  There's hundreds of thousands of certs in the database that are expired.  I was wanting to just start from scratch to get a clean start and also change the name of the server in the process.

Comment: As far as I know there is no attribute on the cert or the database that can easily identify those certs. I don't know if it could work for you but something that cames to mind is getting your autoenrollment template (if you use one) and using PSDrive Cert: query your workstations for those certs that matches your template's attributes. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could [open the certificate store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$CertStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("\\computername\MY","LocalMachine")
$CertStore.Open("ReadOnly")
$CertStore.Certificate # this property contains all the certificates.
```

You could open the local machine personal store on each computer you want to audit and enumerate and return information about certificates ***not*** issued by your new CA

```
$Computers = "adbertram01","adbertram02","adbertram03"
$oldCerts = @() # This will contain all the interesting certificates

foreach($Computer in $Computers) 
{
    $CertStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("\\$Computer\MY","LocalMachine")
    $CertStore.Open("ReadOnly")

    if(!$CertStore.Certificates.Count -gt 0)
    {
        continue # No certificates found, move along
    }

    foreach($Cert in $CertStore.Certificates)
    {
        if($Cert.Issuer -notmatch "MyNew2012CA")
        {
            $oldCerts += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Computer   = $Computer
                    Subject    = $Cert.Subject
                    Issuer     = $Cert.Issuer
                    Thumbprint = $c.Thumbprint
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can see what computers/servers still have certificates from the old CA's installed:

```
$oldCerts |Group-Object -Property Computer
```